# Fire frequency Map in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

I would like to create a fire frequency map in ArcGIS showing the areas which have burnt 1, 2, 3 times etc (overlapping areas). Currently I have years from 2000 to 2014 of burnt area MODIS data which I have converted into polygons but I'm really struggling to figure out how to do this

Comment: You really need to ask a more specific question

Comment: What is not specific enough? I would like to create a map showing the number of times an area has burnt. How do I go about doing that with the polygon layers I have of each year (2000-2014). I need to know the process which will help me create overlapped areas and the times they experienced it (frequency)

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71312/finding-overlapped-areas-and-identifying-their-frequencies-in-a-polygon-layer < this is the exact same question but it hasn't been answered

Comment: by the way, a global raster layer of fire frequency can be downloaded there http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/

Comment: See a previous answer of mine: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/119450/8104. All you need to do is adjust the symbology after running the count polygons tool.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the tool "feature to polygons" which will take overlapping polygons and create "flat" polygons from that, which can then be used with their centroid points and a spatial join to the stacked, original polygons to count the number of occurences.

The blog post at http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/13/spaghetti_and_meatballs/ describes this method.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the [Overlay toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Overlay_toolset/000800000009000000/), see which works best for you.