# How to delete overlay within the same feature class?

Tags: overlay

So, the following scenario:
I have plenty of polygons that are within another polygon, all in the same feature class. All of the polygons (the one overlaping the other ones as well as the ones being overlapped) have attributes which are important for my project. What I basically want is to erase those parts of the selected polygon (see screenshot below) that overlap with other polygons in the same feature class.

http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/8440e2-1461147192.jpg

This is basically just reparing an error which went unnoticed for some time during an editing session and using the auto-complete-polygon option. The selected feature is supposed to be railtracks... you can surely guess what happened there. First step would be just to delete the overlaps, the rest I can do manually with the split-polygon tool.

//Edit: I'm using Esri ArcGIS 10.2.2

Comment: Hi, can you edit your question to tell us the software you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you do, Make a backup of your layer in case if it becomes corrupt.
You should be able to do the following:

If you are doing a few then do this:

1. Start Editing.
2. Click on the Attributes
3. Use the "Edit Tool "
4. Drag over a polygon.
5. On the Attributes, See if there are two overlaps.
6. If you see two overlaps, delete the ones you wanted.

If you are doing the whole polygons then do this but be caution on it:

You could import it to File Geodatabase and create a dataset to 
run a topology. 
Use Topology to set up a rule "Must Not overlap"

If this is not what you looking for then there is another forum that talks about count overlaps on polygons
[Counting overlapping polygons from one Shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119439/how-to-count-overlapping-polygons-from-one-shapefile)